# upshot js change tracking in child entities

Tags: upshot, single-page-application

I have the following model defined in .NET:

```
 Public Class Request
  <Key()>
  Public Property RequestId As String
  Public Property Description As String
  Public Property InfoCards As List(Of InfoCard)
End Class

Public Class InfoCard
  <Key()>
  Public Property InfocardId As String
  Public Property Description As String
  Public Property RequestId As String
End Class
```

The *ReqeuestId* property on the InfoCard is so that EF Code First can generate the db.
I then use the `UpshotContext` helper to generate the JavaScript model like so:

```
Html.UpshotContext(bufferChanges:= true) _
  .DataSource(Of UpshotTest.UpshotTest.RequestController)(Function(x) x.GetRequests()) _
  .ClientMapping(Of UpshotTest.Models.Request)("Request") _
  .ClientMapping(Of UpshotTest.Models.InfoCard)("InfoCard")
```

This generates all models nicely, and when I call `refresh` on the upshot dataSource, the data is retrieved as expected.

The **problem** I am facing is when I attempt to modify a property of a child object (e.q. `Request.InfoCards(0).Description`). Changing that value will trigger the change in the `InfoCard`, but not in the `Request` entity. So, calling `Request.IsUpdated()` will return ***false***, whilst calling `Request.InfoCards(0).IsUpdated()` will return ***true***.

Does upshot not know how to track changes in child entities? Or is it a problem with the mappings on the client side?
So far I have tried several mappings:

- mapping all properties manually:

  ```
  window.Request = function (initialData) {
      var self = this;
      self.RequestId = ko.observable(initialData.RequestId);
      self.Description = ko.observable(initialData.Description);
      self.InfoCards = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(initialData.InfoCards, function (data) {
         return new window.InfoCard(data);
      }));

      upshot.addEntityProperties(self, "Request:#UpshotTest.Models");
  };
  ```
- using `upshot.map`:

  ```
  window.Request = function (initialData) {
      var self = this;
      upshot.map(initialData, upshot.type(Request), self);
  };
  ```
- defining my own *map* function and passing it to upshot:

  ```
  window.Request = function (initialData) {
      var self = this;
      upshot.observability.configuration.map(initialData, upshot.type(Request), map, self);
  };
  ```

The mappings seem correct with all approaches, except the parent entity is not aware of modifications done in its children. Is child tracking even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue in the end. As it turns out, this behavior was reproducible when a hierarchy of 3 nested entities existed (i.e. *Request -> InfoCard -> InfoField*. Modifying a value of the *InfoField* did not reflect in the parent entity.

After many hours of upshot debugging, I found the culprit to be the `_addTrackingRecursive` method in **upshot.js**. Replacing the `obs.track(obj, this._getTracker(), this._entityType);` call to `obs.track(obj, this._getTracker(), type);` solved the nested change tracking issue.